# Accessing a Windows shared drive on a remote server in Python

Tags: python, windows, shared-directory

This seems like a simple problem, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I set up a shared folder on a remote server so that the folder shows up in the Windows Explorer as follows: \\server-name\shared-directory.  I am able to read from that folder remotely and write to that folder remotely via the Windows Explorer.  When I try to access that file via a python script, however, I it says the directory does not exist.

I have administrative rights to the server and gave myself access to the shared drive (I verified this by copying files via Windows Explorer).

In python, I am accessing the drive as follows (although I tried several different ways and had no success):

```
os.access('\\\\server-name\\path-to-shared-directory', os.W_OK)
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT:

In response to questions, I am actually trying to copy files using the script, os.access was just used to see if the directory had write access.  The copy code I am using is as follows:

```
def copy_folder(src, dest):
    if not os.access(dest, os.W_OK):
        return(False)
    cmd = ['xcopy', '/E', '/J', '/Y', '/I', src, dest]

    p = subprocess.Popen(args=cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    out, err = p.communicate()

    print 'out: %s' % out
    print 'err: %s' % err

    return(True)

copy_folder(my_source_directory, '\\\\server-name\\path-to-shared-directory')
```

This returns 'Invalid drive specification' as an error.

Comment: Since `os.access` returns `True` or `False`, it's unlikely that the code snippet you posted tells you that the folder doesn't exist. Can you post the real code and the stack trace you get?

Comment: **What error message are you getting?**

Comment: can you not assign the share a drive letter and `os.chdir` to the mount?

Comment: See edit to my question.

Comment: @tMC: os.chdir says 'The network name cannot be found'.  This error seems misleading since I can connect via Windows Explorer.  Any ideas?

Comment: Connecting to the network location via Explorer isn't the same as mapping it to a drive letter though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have no problem accessing files via the UNC path that you are already attempting to use, but I would recommend formatting it a bit differently to help with escaping:

```
src  = r'C:\path\to\source'
dest = r'\\server-name\path-to-shared-directory'
```

And you don't need `stdin`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
        shell=True)
```

Normally you would be able to use forward slashes for paths in python, but since you are calling out to a shell command, the backslashes are still needed.

Comment: I tried converting the strings over to the format you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect it might have something to do with the Windows Share and not python?

Comment: Can you expand on the part that "Doesn't work"? What is the error? What is the result? If you can access the share from that same path in explorer, I would assume it should work from your python script on that same machine.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have said that it gives the same result as my initial code.  That's why I thought it might have something to do with the Windows share drive and not python.  Windows Explorer can access the file without issue.

Comment: Well I just tested this exact example and it works for me, so I would have to suspect you are right in thinking its related to your network permissions or something of that nature.

Comment: What is the value of `my_source_directory ` ?

Comment: my_source_directory is in the same format as you described above and has access via os.access. i.e. r'C:\some_path'

Comment: Are there any spaces in the paths? Does it work when you use a local destination path?

Comment: I have another shared path on the same server (set up a while ago) that works fine.  Also, the local paths work fine as well.

Comment: Solved, now I feel like an idiot... There was a typo in my shared drive name...  I'll mark this as correct since it best describes a solution to the problem.